# How to customize Wordpress edit post page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add some extra form fields to an existing page in Wordpress.
This page is where you are redirected whenever you edit a post or page.
My problem is I don't know where to find this file or what its called.

I need to know what file i need to edit in order to be able to add the new inputs.

this page would only be seen if you are an administrator and logged in and in dashboard.

I'm using wordpress edge shuffle theme.

Comment: Try ACF plugin.. That's what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to use Advanced Custom Fields. ACF allows you to specify custom fields that appear on certain edit pages in the admin. You'll then have custom data to use on your frontend templates.
Check out [this tutorial](https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/tutorials/how-to-use-acf-wordpress/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as I was just trying to figure out how to edit my posts page

While logged on to my admin account to edit, I went to my actual page and the top admin bar had an option of "customize" and that took me where I needed to go to add some css

[image]